# Generating wlfullclient.jar error (WebLogic 12c)

Tags: java, jar, weblogic

I've installed WebLogic 12c developer zip. The server is up and running. But when I try to generate wlfullclient.jar from the wljarbuilder.jar the following error occurs:

```
C:\weblogic\wls\wls12120\wlserver\server\lib>java -jar wljarbuilder.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\weblogic\wls\wls12120\wlserver\server\lib\webl
ogic-classes.jar
        at com.bea.jarbuilder.internal.CompositeJar.<init>(CompositeJar.java:69)

        at com.bea.jarbuilder.JarBuilder.createJar(JarBuilder.java:165)
        at com.bea.jarbuilder.JarBuilder.main(JarBuilder.java:53)
Error creating target jar
```

It's missing the weblogic-classes.jar from the lib folder. But I've reinstalled the server and this jar isn't there.
How can I solve this problem to generate the client full jar?

Comment: Sounds stupid... but what if you copy the regular server/lib/weblogic.jar to server/lib/weblogic-classes.jar ? Could be a bug in 12c

Comment: You mean copying and renaming the weblogic.jar to weblogic-classes.jar? Because the I can't find the weblogic-classes.jar anywhere.

Comment: Yes - try what you said

Comment: It's seems to have worked! I'll test the wlfullclient.jar in my app now and return with a feedback. Do you think the "weblogic-classes.jar" is the same as "weblogic.jar"?

Comment: Yes. In 10.3.6 it looks for weblogic.jar first. There is no weblogic-classes.jar file in 10.3.6 either.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: Following better_use_mkstemp's suggestion (on WLS v12.1.2.0.0), then running *wljarbuilder* resulted in an incomplete "wlfullclient.jar". - Among others, the cruicial `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` was missing.

So what I did was to copy **`wlclient.jar`** to "weblogic-classes.jar" and, via *wljarbuilder*, got myself a single, working "wlfullclient.jar".
(Make sure you delete the redundant "weblogic-classes.jar" afterwards to avoid future trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

The developer version of WebLogic misses some features. 
You could reinstall a new instance of WebLogic by the installers.
Or as I did, you could run the oracle provided WebLogic docker. It generates a wlfullclient.jar nicely. I just recently did it.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the Developer Zip to generated the full client. There are still missing classes. Use the weblogic installers.